# CQLSH after Mavericks: now with missing "t"

Tags: cassandra, cql3

After upgrading to Mavericks(OSX 10.9) I can not longer input a lowercase "t".  "T" works fine.  It does not matter if I type or copy and paste.

Has anyone see this before?

```
python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

when I try to enter this command:

```
 select * from methylation450 where cancer='BRCA' and gene_name='PTGS2' limit 10;
```

I get the following output:

```
selec* from meylaon450 where cancer='BRCA' and gene_name='PTGS2' limi10;
```

Running the same query as a file cqlsh -f cmd.file works just fine

Comment: I'm using Mavericks and python 2.7.5 and can't replicate inside or outside cqlsh.

Comment: can you give me the output of "set"?

Comment: there's a lot to it - what are you looking for?

Comment: I am not really sure.  I was just hoping to compare, and see if something jumps out as the problem

Comment: Is t working in the regular python interpreter? Off the top of my head it sounds like someone is pranking you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Mac OSX Mavericks, I also saw this issue after configuring SSL for cqlsh.

After running easy_install readline as a super user, running reset in the Terminal, and restarting cqlsh, I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing readline on the mac and see if that resolves it.

Comment: It's already installed.  Tried removing and reinstalling, still not luck

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I've heard of one other person experiencing this issue.  readline was the best guess for root cause. Perhaps you can provide additional details on the Mac environment?

Answer (score 1):

Try running 'reset' once on the terminal. Terminal.app (and iTerm) maintain some state across restarts, so it's possible something that jacks up the terminal is being preserved. The reset command sends an escape code to the terminal emulator that tells it to reset state.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset

If that doesn't work, please send the output of 'env' or at least 'echo $TERM'.

Comment: No luck with reset, tried this is SecureCRT and Terminal.    Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-YMmRt0/Render
BASH=/bin/bash
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
IFS=$' \t\n'
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=schappetj
MACHTYPE=x86_64-apple-darwin13
OSTYPE=darwin13
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:vi
SHLVL=1
TERM=xterm